# content slider (still moving)

Tags: jquery, css

Hello I have created slider with a content, but now I am wondering how could I do just a trick, that if I have items  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | they all are visible, and slide very slowly into left. How could I get this? I mean that I have ul with li elements, and they all are sliding from right to the left?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Give your Code or use the www.jsfiddle.net to share your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think css transition is what you looking for. More information to study [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp).

Example to [see](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css3-image-slider)